# Functional form of binary independent variable

Tags: regression, binary-data, polynomial, categorical-encoding

I am considering a model with a dummy variable on the right hand side. The dummy variable takes the value 1 when an underlying continuous variable is greater than some threshold and zero otherwise. What type of function is the dependent variable with respect to the continuous variable?

Comment: How do you get from $y_i = a + e_i$ if the dummy variable for observation $i$ takes on the value $0$ or $y_i = b + e_i$ if the dummy variable for observation $i$ takes on the value $1$, where $b = a + \beta$, $\beta$ being the coefficient on the dummy variable, to thinking there's a cubic relationship?

Comment: I only ask because I don’t know. I thought it might be cubic as there are two turning points

Answer (score 1):

Many different models, with different functional forms, can have "a dummy variable on the right hand side". For example, the equation

$$μ_Y = b_0 + b_1X$$

where $X$ is a dummy variable is linear, not cubic, in its coefficients. Note that even if $X$ were not a dummy variable and you raised it to the third power, the model would still be a linear model, because the "linear" in "linear model" refers to the relationship between the model parameters and the covariates, not to any non-parametrized transformations that you apply to the covariates.